# Link to open jQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm trying to open an accordion div from an external link. I see the "navigation: true" option but I'm not sure how to implement it. Do you give each div an id and call the link like this? http://domain.com/link#anchorid

I'm new to jQuery so bear with me. Here is the code I'm using if it helps.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h2", autoHeight: false, animated: false, navigation: true });
         });
    </script>
<div id="accordion">

<div>
    <h2><a href="#">Services</a></h2>
    <div class="services">
    <p>More information about all of these services</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The navigation option isn't for panel activation.  It's for telling the user where they are.

Using simplified html code:

```
<div id="accordion">

    <div>
        <h2><a href="#services">Services</a></h2>
        <p>More information about all of these services</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2><a href="#about">About</a></h2>
        <p>About us</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

You put the unique ID in the Hyperlink in the title

Then the jQuery (simplified):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h2", navigation: true });
     });
</script>
```

The "navigation : true" will enable you to go www.site.com/#about which makes the "about" panel selected.  For activation, there are a couple of ways.  Perhaps one way is to grab a query string and put it into the jQuery.

With C#

```
$("#accordion").accordion("activate", '<%= Request.QueryString["id"] %>');
```

With PHP

```
$("#accordion").accordion("activate", '<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>');
```

Which will allow you to specify which panel to open by www.site.com?id=2

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help

Comment: In c# you have to remove the single quotes:
$("#accordion").accordion("activate", <%= Request.QueryString["id"] %>);

Comment: ASP.Net will process whatever is inside the <%= %> and return the result in that space. C# doesn't care what's outside those brackets. In addition, since querySTRINGS are strings, it's generally safer to pass a string. If you omitted the quotes, and the querystring was "?id=pane4", JS would look for a variable or constant called "pane4" instead of letting jQuery figure out what the to do with it. In practice, both may work, but putting it in quotes is the safer approach, imho.
It also allows you to use selector matching. see here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion/activate

Comment: In the newer versions of jQuery it's something like: `("#accordion").accordion('option', 'active', 2);`

Comment: the <?php echo (int)$_GET["id"]; ?> is not working for me.. is there another way to pull in the id?

Answer (score 5):

The `navigation` option which many of these answers refer to was [**deprecated** in jQuery UI 1.9](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-navigation-and-navigationfilter-options) and **removed** in 1.10. The reason given was:

> This functionality was disabled by default and is only one of many ways that you might want to determine which panel to activate on initialization. As such, we've deprecated this in favor of just handling the logic outside of accordion and setting the active option appropriately.

So coders using the newer versions of jQuery UI will need to write their own code to handle this feature.

For my site, I accomplished this with a JavaScript `switch` statement just before the `</body>` tag. (I'm not an experienced coder, so others should feel free to improve this answer.)

```
<script>
function switchToPanel(panel){
    var index = -1;
    switch (panel) {
        case "preschool":
            index = 0;
            break;
        case "kindergarten":
            index = 1;
            break;
        case "1st":
            index = 2;
            break;
        default:
            console.warn("Cannot switch to panel " + panel);
    }
    jQuery('#mathAccordion').accordion({active: index});
}

jQuery().ready(function() {
    if (window.location.hash) { //window.location.hash gets the anchor location out of the URL
        var target = window.location.hash.replace('#', ''); //remove the #
        switchToPanel(target);
    }
});
</script>
```

Here's the corresponding HTML:

```
<div class="accordion" id="mathAccordion">
    <h1>Preschool</h1>
    <div class="accordionFold">Preschool content</div>
    <h1>Kindergarten</h1>
    <div class="accordionFold">Kindergarten content</div>
    <h1>1st Grade</h1>
    <div class="accordionFold">First grade content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hah, cracked it.

Use the php get method. However there is an error in the one above.
$("#accordion").accordion("activate", '');

the php code needs the quotation marks removed.

Works a treat now.

Cheers

Ian

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        navigation: true,
        header: ".menuitem"
     });

    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var anchor = $('a[href$="'+hash+'"]');
    if (anchor.length > 0){
        anchor.click();
    }
});
</script>
```

and the html...

```
<div id="accordion">
        <h3 class="menuitem"><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></h3>
        <div>
            More data....
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With a server-side language, check the query for that #anchor and use it to fill out the activation statement.

Extracted from something I was just working on:

```
$("#search_forms").accordion("activate", "{$this->open_form}");
```

**Edit:**

I can't link directly to the accordion method blurb, but this gets you close:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#methods

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me...

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$("#accordion").accordion("activate", hash);
```

Comment: I went one better:
`$("#accordion").accordion("activate", window.location.hash);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $("#accordion").accordion("activate", hash);
});
```

this works with jquery 1.8.3 and jqueryui 1.9.1
but didnt seem to work with jqueryui 1.10.0

not sure why...

Comment: activate method was removed in 1.10+ jqueryui