# Jquery Accordion to activate specific panels with anchor tags/url hash

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, hyperlink, accordion

I am having an almost identical problem to the question asked here ( [Link to open jQuery Accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588030/link-to-open-jquery-accordion)? ) but wasn't able to correctly implement the answers.

I tried this solution but it didn't work for me:

```
$("#accordion").accordion("activate", <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>);
```

I have a Jquery accordion with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            // Accordion
            $("#accordion").accordion({ 
                header: "h3", 
                autoHeight: false,
                navigation: true,
                collapsible: true,
                active: false
            });
            $(".exlnk").click(function(event){
      window.location.hash=this.hash;
 });    

        });


</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Click1(){  
$("#accordion").accordion('activate' , 0)
} 
function Click2(){  
$("#accordion").accordion('activate' , 1)
} 

</script>
```

Simplified HTML:

```
 <h3><a class="exlnk" href="#about" title="About">About</a></h3>
<div>content blah blah</div>
<h3><a class="exlnk" href="#about" title="About">About</a></h3>
<div>Blah blah</div>
```

The above code allows me to have links on the main page that will activate the specified panel.

The exlnk bit gives each panel a hash upon clicking it, which I read on this tutorial ( http://www.michaeljacobdavis.com/tutorials/statesavingaccordion.html ) would create state-saving, book-markable panels.  It assigns the hash, but it doesn't activate the panels or save them from closing on re-load.

What I want is to be able to link externally to http://www.mysite.com/page#anchor and have it open the page with the appropriate panel open.  My work-around to be able link from the accordion page is only so useful!

Thanks SO MUCH for any help...I have read every Q&A on this site related to the Accordion script and was not able to make any of the answers work.  I am very very new to Jquery/Javascript, so answers that explain all the steps of implementation and where to place each suggested code would be wonderful.

Comment: It would be useful to see the JS fragment generated by `$("#accordion").accordion("activate", <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>);`

Comment: Maybe that's what I'm missing - in my attempts to use that snippet, it was just sitting in my accordion code and not referenced or called in any other way.

Comment: hey, I just did a quick accordian for you here:
[link](http://weblopper.com.au/accordian/index.html)

I guess it is according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the example. That is how mine is currently functioning -- what I'd like to happen is if, using your example, I type in http://weblopper.com.au/accordian/index.html#second, the page would load with the second accordion panel open.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to tie in your server-side code with the `.activate()` method which should let you dynamically show a panel based on what is passed as the index or selector:

> Activate a content part of the Accordion programmatically. The index
>   can be a zero-indexed number to match the position of the header to
>   close or a Selector matching an element. Pass `false` to close all (only
>   possible with `collapsible:true` ).

**Example:**

If possible, instead of passing `$_GET['id']`, pass the name of the selector matching the element that you want activated. For example:

```
$("#accordion").accordion("activate", "#<?php echo $_GET['tab']; ?>");
```

`$_GET['tab']` would be the name of the selector your passing. Of course, if the selector needs to be a class, just change the hash to a period.

If you wanted to have something activated based on a link like http://www.mysite.com/page#anchor you'll want to grab the hash with javascript when your page loads and use that hash (which would be the name of the selector that will activate your panel) in place of `$_GET['id']`

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!  Sounds like what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to carry it out -- do you have an example of what the changes to my code would look like?

Comment: You're welcome. I've edited my answer to provide an example :)

Comment: Hm...for the code $("#accordion").accordion("activate", "#"); doesn't it have to be the id of the panel in order for it to work?  For example, to activate the first panel the code is $("#accordion").accordion("activate", "0");

Comment: Oh, yeah you can certainly use the indexes of the panels instead of a selector (with no quotes of course), but I was just trying to show that you can pass a selector around and use that to activate the panels instead of using the elements index. Also, what you said about using the id of the panel in order for it to work: it's not the id you're using if you're using numbers. It's the index of the element. If you have 3 tabs, you'd have indexes of 0, 1, and 2. Hope that helps!