# Could you show how we can open a specific tab in the accordion from another page?

Tags: accordion

I have been following tutorials from "learnnerd", a Youtube contributer. [Url here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjHt_v6nK_E&list=UU08OUGXLKqlnADsUDqA8evg&index=2&feature=plcp)
I have made my website using the codes he provided. [Here's my website](http://www.alliedantennas.com.au).   (check services)

I would like to link a tab on my home page to open a specific accordion in my services pages. I've researched but still know little. I don't know much about Javascript.
My php/html code looks like:

```
<h2 class="accordion"><a href="#1"> Antenna</a></h2>
<h2 class="accordion"><a href="#2"> Digital</a></h2>
```

My script (from "learnnerd (Youtube)" and Atomix(here)) looks like this:

```
$(function(){   
   $('.accContainer').hide(); //hide all content        
   $('.accordion').click(function(){
    if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
    $('.accordion').next().slideUp();
    //triggers the hiding of contents
    $(this).next().slideDown();
    //triggers slide down of contents
    }
     return false; //prevents brower default
   });

   $(".accordion").accordion({ 
     header: "h2", navigation: true 
   }); 
}); //document.ready function
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search a little more on this site.  I believe this already answered question should help you:

[Link to open jQuery Accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588030/link-to-open-jquery-accordion?rq=1)

Comment: Hello, I have tried to use information from the link you provided but still cannot get a solution. I have editted my post and included the php/hml and script codes. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not very certain what the click function does for the accordion.  If you get rid of it, I think it should work. Jquery handles all that for you when make the call to create the accordion.  I don't see the purpose of that code.

Comment: Your accordions are empty too btw.  Follow the advice in the link to create a working accordion and ditch your code.

Comment: You're making a classic mistake of not letting JQuery do the work, which is what I assume you are using. I threw the stuff in from the link into a jsfiddle with some modifications to show you how to directly open a link with code.  Unfortunately, jsfiddle does not seem like it will let you test the navigation.  http://jsfiddle.net/FXQgP/

Comment: here is a working jsfiddle..modified and versionised one http://jsfiddle.net/FXQgP/4/ provided by @user1441141