# Jquery UI accordion menu

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have created a jquery accordion menu inside a user control and used that user control in the project master page.

I want set the active index (Leave it open :)) of the accordion based on the hyperlink, the user is clicking.

User control code,

```
<div id="accordion1">       
    <div class="headeritem"><asp:Image runat="server" CssClass="headerimage" ImageUrl="" /><span class="headerspan">link1</span></div>
    <div class="content">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlMenuItem1" runat="server" Text="Search Appearances" NavigateUrl="" CssClass="menuitem"></asp:HyperLink>        
    </div>
    <div class="headeritem"><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass="headerimage" ImageUrl="" /><span class="headerspan">Link2</span></div>
    <div class="content">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlMenuItem4" runat="server" Text="Published Feedback" NavigateUrl="" CssClass="menuitem"></asp:HyperLink>        
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I save the index value when the link is clicked?

Comment: This thread may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588030/link-to-open-jquery-accordion

Comment: To Open a specific panel you can use the active param like `$("#accordion1").accordion({
        active: 1
    });`. For getting this index you might need to do some jquery find to get the position in your dom and call accordion appropriately.

Comment: @BillyMoat Is there anyway without using querystring?

Comment: @Joshua - Not sure I'm afraid. Here's the API Documentation if it's the jQuery UI Accordion that you're using: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed the index through a query string and retrieving that value to set the active index.